# Shortest shell code to run both traceroute and traceroute6

Tags: shell, perl, xargs, tcsh

I'd like to run both `traceroute -w2` and `traceroute6 -w2`, sequentially, in a shell script, to try out multiple different hosts.

A naive approach may just use a temporary variable to gather all the hosts within (e.g., set `HOSTS` to `ordns.he.net one.one.one.one google-public-dns-a.google.com`), and then just pipe it individually to each command, like, `echo $HOSTS | xargs -n1 traceroute -w2` et al, but this would work differently in `tcsh` than in `bash`, and may be prone to mistakes if you want to add more commands (as you'd be adding those as code as opposed to a list of things to do), and I'm thinking there's some better way to join together the ***list of commands*** (e.g., a command name with a single parameter) with the ***list of arguments*** (e.g., hostnames in our example), for the shell to execute every possible combination.

I've tried doing some combination of `xargs -n1` (for hosts) and `xargs -n2` (for commands with one parameter) piping into each other, but it didn't really make much sense and didn't work.

I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use any GNU tools and would work in a base OpenBSD install (if necessary, `perl` is part of the base OpenBSD, so, it's available as well).

Comment: Why is tcsh involved in this question when OpenBSD has a perfectly good POSIX sh? csh is a relic of the days when pre-POSIX (which is to say, pre-1992) Bourne had an inadequate featureset, and ksh was commercially licensed and cost money; neither of those things has been true for decades.

Comment: ...larger issue: Optimizing for terseness over correctness in shell languages is a bad idea in general. There's a lot of historical baggage in shell -- pretty much the full family of languages inspired by or attempting to be backwards-compatible with any 1970s-era shell -- and working around it generally makes some amount of baggage obligatory.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that's because I use tcsh as my main shell (I like the FreeBSD's default of `history-search-backward` for `bindkey -k up` on my systems), and this is intended to be a snippet for my shell

Comment: @cnst I also use `tcsh` as my command-line interpreter, for a few conveniences for daily work, one of which you mention (I bind it to Ctrl-P).  (But I'm considering changing to `bash` for its many other advantages.)  But then I have a `~/bin` where there are various utilities, and these are mostly `bash` scripts (and a few in Perl, and a few C programs working via `precmd` and `period` shell features).  You aren't tied to `tcsh` for that, and this looks like just a thing that could be done in a nice li'l script.

Comment: The simple solution to "some things are not compatible with tcsh" is to not use tcsh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have perl:

```
perl -e 'for(@ARGV){ print qx{  traceroute -w2 -- $_; traceroute6 -w2 -- $_ } }' google.com debian.org
```

As for a better way to join together the list of commands (e.g., a command name with a single parameter) with the list of arguments (e.g., hostnames) the answer could be GNU Parallel, which is built for doing just that:

```
parallel "{1}" -w2 -- "{2}" ::: traceroute traceroute6 ::: google.com debian.org
```

If you want special arguments connected with each command you can do:

```
parallel eval "{1}" -- "{2}" ::: "traceroute -a -w2" "traceroute6 -w2" ::: google.com debian.org
```

The `eval` is needed because GNU Parallel quotes all input, and while you normally want that, we do not want that in this case.

But since that is a GNU tool, it is out of scope for your question. It is only included here for other people that read your question and who do not have that limitation.

Comment: Thanks for the tool!  I've used it in some earlier project a few years ago. :-)  Is there an alternative to `{1}`?  It gets expanded to `1` in tcsh, and `\{1}` is a bit ugly.  Also, it seems that I get some output out-of-order, e.g., I get some initial banners from `traceroute6` at the bottom of the output (e.g., running your example ends with the following line: `traceroute6 to google.com (2607:f8b0:4005:809::200e) from 2607:fb90:…`, which seems out of place and out-of-order).

Comment: You can protect against `tcsh` interpretation by quoting. "{1}" or '{1}' or quoting the whole string. The out-of-order is probably traceroute that prints both to stderr and stdout. GNU Parallel prints stdout first followed by stderr. You can avoid that by redirecting stderr to stdout in your command.

Comment: So, how do you do the stderr/stdout merge/redirect as part of parallel?  What about the original problem statement — can I have a list of commands with one argument each?  E.g., maybe `traceroute` needs `-aw2`, but `traceroute6` doesn't support `-a` so, gets just `-w2`?  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @cnst It is unclear to me what you ask. List the actually commands you want run, and then let us see.

Comment: I have the issue that stdout/stderr are not printed in order by `parallel`, compared to what `traceroute6` outputs if you run it outside of `parallel`.  How do I redirect traceroute6's stderr to stdout as you've mentioned earlier, within parallel?

Comment: OK, seems like the following works:  `parallel eval \{1} -w2 -- \{2} '2>&1' ::: "traceroute -a" traceroute6 ::: ordns.he.net one.one.one.one`.  Kinda hairy, but I guess it does work, and is pretty short? :-)

Comment: It seems that I'm getting the output out-of-order (e.g., a random order for each command), and also it would seem that some `traceroute` instances must be getting killed, as they fail to run to full completion, showing only, like, the first line with the first host.  Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I need more info. Maybe post a new question with an MCVE?

Comment: Well, the order is always random, but the traceroute instances getting killed seems to vary.  Is there a way to get the output in the very same order in which the arguments are provided?

Comment: Use --keep-order

Answer (score 4):

Keeping it simple:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -- host1 host2 host3 host4 ...
for host do traceroute -w2 -- "$host"; done
for host do traceroute6 -w2 -- "$host"; done
```

Comment: This is not an answer, because, 1, it requires `sh`, and, 2, it it's already known as part of the question.  Plus, it's hardly a snippet that could be copy-pasted within the shell, which is what the whole purpose of the question is about.

Comment: The `shell` tag, which you used, is for POSIX sh (which, per your spec, OpenBSD ships with). I've read and reread the question and see no evidence of (2).

Comment: I guess he never learned you [don't look at gift-horse in the mouth](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24539/dont-look-a-gift-horse-in-the-mouth)...

Comment: @cnst This most certainly is an answer (and a good one, as an indication which way to go, as far as I'm concerned). You have every right to not like it of course, but your response to it comes across as rude.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, as for (2), I don't see how your solution is different from the `echo $HOSTS | xargs -n1 traceroute -w2` that's present in the question; in fact, you never explain what `--` is for, and I think it caused the other answer to use the `--` for no particular reason as well.

Comment: @cnst, `--` is an end-of-options sigil, as standardized in [POSIX utility syntax guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) #10: *The first `--` argument that is not an option-argument should be accepted as a delimiter indicating the end of options. Any following arguments should be treated as operands, even if they begin with the `-` character.* -- thus, it prevents a hostname starting with a dash from being treated as a collection of single-character options to `traceroute`.

Comment: @cnst, ...if your copy of `traceroute` doesn't support it, then it's failing to comply with the relevant standard, which should be reported upstream as a bug.

Comment: @cnst, ...and use of `echo $HOSTS | xargs` is buggy, full-stop. You get unwanted glob expansion (f/e, `foo[bar]` in the inputs gets matched against local filenames and thus potentially replaced with `foob`, `fooa`, etc; and also can trigger outright failures if `globfail` is set, or silently disappear when run on a shell with the `nullglob` option). You also get xargs doing not-quite-shell-compatible parsing of quotes and other characters in your strings, and various weirdness falling out of that, so you can't safely use it for arbitrary content.

Comment: @cnst, ...see [BashPitfalls #56](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#Using_xargs_without_-0) and [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy these would all be very valid points, but not in this context.  However, thanks for teaching me `--` — I've been asked multiple times about deleting files like `-rf` in various interviews, and my only solution was always `./-rf`, and no interviewer ever revealed the `--` part — good to know!

Answer (score 0):

With [GNU Parallel](http://ports.su/sysutils/parallel), the final solution for the problem at stake would be something like the following snippet, using [`tcsh`](http://ports.su/shells/tcsh) syntax, and OS X `traceroute` and `traceroute6`:

`( history 1 ; parallel --keep-order -j4 eval \{1} -w1 -- \{2} '2>&1' ::: "traceroute -a -f1" traceroute6 ::: ordns.he.net ns{1,2,3,4,5}.he.net one.one.one.one google-public-dns-a.google.com resolver1.opendns.com ; history 1 ) | & mail -s "traceroute: ordns.he.net et al from X" receipient@example.org -f sender@example.org`